# D3 line chart color and width issues

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm making a line chart with a context so you can zoom in on specific dates.

[I got some issues with my coloring and my width however.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1o4c.png)

At the first time when i draw the chart the lines are all the same color. I think this has something to so with how I give my ID's to the certain pieces of the lines. (I've tried giving the colors in CSS styling via ID as well as in javascript)

```
dataGroup.forEach(function(d, i) {
var key = d.key;
channel.append('svg:path')
.attr("d", line(d.values))
.attr("class",function(d){
          if(check)return "lijn2";else return "lijn"})
.attr("mouseZoomable",function(d){
          if(check)return false;else return true})
.attr('id',function(d){return d.key.replace(/\W+/g, "").replace(/ /g,"").toLowerCase();})
.attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
.attr('stroke', function(d, j) 
{
  var colorI=0;

  for(var r = 0;r<colorArray.length;r++)
  {
    if(colorArray[r].State.toString().replace(/\W+/g, "").replace(/ /g,"").toLowerCase() ==d. key.replace(/\W+/g, "").replace(/ /g,"").toLowerCase())
    {
      return localColorScale[colorArray[r].color];
    }
  }
}
)
}
```

Datagroup is een array with 10 useable channels to distribute information, which all have an independent array as value. This array has all counts of which this channel was used on a particular day.

```
Object
key: "Google+"
values: Array (8)
0 {state: "Google+", date: 1456786800000, count: "543"}
1 {state: "Google+", date: 1456873200000, count: "360"}
2 {state: "Google+", date: 1456959600000, count: "162"}
3 {state: "Google+", date: 1457046000000, count: "483"}
4 {state: "Google+", date: 1457132400000, count: "590"}    
5 {state: "Google+", date: 1457218800000, count: "645"}
6 {state: "Google+", date: 1457305200000, count: "129"}
7 {state: "Google+", date: 1457391600000, count: "188"}
```

[Selecting a certain area fixes colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZ1C2.png) but totally weirds out the width of the chart. The focusing on certain pieces of charts uses the same axis, so i don't know why the width is getting weird.

My coding skills are far from perfect. So any help on improving or fixing this issue is greatly appreciated. If you need any more information (or if something isn't clear) please do ask!
thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to use a clip-path, this is a good example which illustrates the use http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4015254

Comment: @Cyril I need the extent of the below graph to be the new domain of my above chart. How can i give the extent to clip path? Because the given example just uses the zoom function to enlarge or shrink the given graph.

Comment: I am not sure about your question in the comment. But if you put up a working fiddle people may be able to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry @Cyril, i re-read your first answer and kinda dissected it, and you were correct. Thanks for the quick and correct answer!